# How to upgrade to Airflow 2.0?

Tags: airflow

Now that Airflow 2.0 is [released](http://airflow.apache.org/blog/airflow-two-point-oh-is-here/), we're excited to try out some the new features.

- What's the best way of upgrading from 1.10.11 to Airflow 2.0?
- Will my existing code work or will I be required to change my DAGs?

We'll start upgrading in our DEV environment for testing later this week.

Airflow 1.10.11 and local executor and Python3

Answer (score 7):

The documentation lacks the information, how to exactly upgrade to 1.10.14 while the newer version is already available.

According to the PIP documentation (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-packages) this should work:

```
python -m pip install apache-airflow==1.10.14
```

This seemed to work for me, but I was not able to start the websever after.

First, I had to upgrade the DB:

```
airflow upgradedb
```

Second, starting the webserver showed the problem that now the "secret_key" has to contain a real secret key.

Execute

```
openssl rand -hex 30
```

and add the hex key to the airflow.cfg file.

Then follow the remaining steps (including executing the check script) from the upgrade documentation.

As it is not described, either, the actual upgrade to 2.0 should work by using

```
pip install -U apache-airflow
```

Note especially the change in the DB upgrade command (`airflow db upgrade` instead of `airflow upgradedb`).

Regards,
HerrB92

Answer (score 4):

We have documented it at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html

**Step 1**: Upgrade to Python 3

**Step 2**: Upgrade to Airflow 1.10.14 (a.k.a Airflow "bridge" release)

**Step 3**: Install and run the Airflow Upgrade check scripts (https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-upgrade-check/)

**Step 4**: Import Operators from Backport Providers

**Step 5**: Upgrade Airflow DAGs

**Step 6**: Upgrade Configuration settings

**Step 7**: Upgrade to Airflow 2.0

The upgrade-check package should help you in upgrading.

Read https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/upgrading-to-2.html#step-3-install-and-run-the-upgrade-check-scripts

Comment: The documentation just says to update to 1.10.14, but Step 2 does not say how to do this.  Step 3 assumes you've already installed it.  I have airflow 1.10.10 currently running - is there an `airflow upgrade` or something?

Comment: Upgrade - `pip install -U apache-airflow` and once installed  `airflow upgradedb` -- same as you would upgrade to any Airflow version

Comment: @kaxil The upgrade documentation mentions that you have to upgrade to 1.10.14 first, but not  - as @d8aninja mentions -, how to exactly upgrade (first) to 1.10.14. `pip install -U apache-airflow` installs directly 2.0+ and it is not quite obvious, how to upgrade to a lower version than the latest.

Comment: @HerrB92 run `pip install -U apache-airflow==1.10.14`